# When exception is being hit in Visual Studio debugging, hovering the exception reveals null

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core-1.1

For some reason, when attempting to debug an application, the exceptions themselves show as null. Initially, I didn't have the SqlException catch section, but I did see that it said it had thrown a SqlException, so figured I'd add to look and the result appears the same.

I did previously remove Visual Studio and reinstalled it (plus the 1.1 asp.net core SDK) so that's the oddball difference between now and before. It is running in Debug.

How do I get it to return the actual error messages so I can debug?

[image]

Comment: Do you have another exception above that is also called `sqlEx` ?

Comment: no, prior to that is the try clause and within it, no internal try/catches. It breaks at db.SaveChanges() and jumps to this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cursor is on the catch clause, the exception will be null. Hit F10 to see it's content.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's strange, previously I could hover over the e (in your example) part and it'd show results, but F10 did pull it so marking this as correct.

Comment: Not sure if it's intended by VS or not, but I remember I always had to do it. I'll take a look if there are similar reports about this